# C++ Problema al imprimir matrices

Tags: c++, array

Quiero hacer este problema: https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/pb-Cuadrado#problems

> #### Problema
>
> Dada una matriz cuadrada de tamaño “n” , debes hacer
>   que tu programa la gire 90 grados a la derecha.
>
> Matriz original
>
> ```
> 1   2
> 3   4
> ```
>
> Matriz Girada 90° a la derecha
>
> ```
> 3   1
> 4   2
> ```

Mi código siento que está bien pero no funciona. A la hora de imprimir **n** matrices, sólo me imprime un numero larguísimo que no tiene nada que ver con la matriz.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    cin>>n;
    int m=n*n;
    int arr[n][n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<m; x++){
        cout<<arr[(n-x)][x];" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es aconsejable incluir la etiqueta `c`, entre otras, porque el enunciado en ***omegaUp*** no especifica el lenguaje. Además el código es altamente compatible con `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Tu programa tiene varios problemas.

El primero de ellos se encuentra en la forma de declarar la matriz:

```
int n=0;
cin>>n;
int arr[n][n];
```

El estándar de C++ indica que crear arreglos en la pila basados en tamaños dinámicos (su tamaño se basa en una variable) producen un resultado indeterminado, lo que viene a decir que en algunos compiladores puede funcionar pero que en otros no. Es una de esas características que no se deberían usar bajo ningún concepto si no quieres llevarte sorpresas desagradables al cambiar de compilador (o incluso de versión del compilador).

Si necesitas que el tamaño de la matriz sea dependiente de una variable deberías usar o contenedores de la STL o memoria dinámica:

**Declaración de una matriz de nxn**

```
// Creación
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n,std::vector<int>(n));

// Uso
arr[fila][columna] = 7;

// Destrucción
// -- no aplicable --
```

**Memoria dinámica v1**

Esta versión simplifica el acceso a costa de complicar la creación y el borrado

```
// Creación
int** arr = new int*[n];
for( auto i=0; i<n; i++ )
  arr[i] = new int[n];

// Uso
arr[fila][columna] = 7;

// Destrucción (opción A)
for( auto i=0; i<n; i++ )
  delete[] arr[i];
delete[] arr;

// Destrucción (opción B)
std::for_each(arr,arr+n,std::default_delete<int[]>());
delete[] arr;
```

**Memoria dinámica v2**

Esta versión simplifica la creación y la destrucción pero complica el acceso.

```
// Creación
int* arr = new int[n*n];

// Uso
arr[fila*n+columna] = 7;

// Destrucción
delete[] arr;
```

Otro problema lo tienes al imprimir los datos:

```
cout<<arr[(n-x)][x];" ";
```

Ese `;` que tienes antes de las comillas hace que el espacio de separación no se imprima nunca... se convierte en una instrucción inutil que no hace absolutamente nada.

Además, dado que únicamente quieres sacar un carácter lo correcto sería sustituir las comillas dobles por comillas simples (comillas dobles = cadena = dos bytes, comillas simples = char = 1 byte).

```
cout<<arr[(n-x][x] << ' ';
```

Por otro lado, el acceso que haces de la matriz a la hora de imprimir los resultados es un poco extraño:

```
for(int x=0; x<m; x++){
    cout<<arr[(n-x)][x]<<' ';
}
```

Si ejecutamos por pasos (suponemos n=2, luego m=4, luego arr[2][2]):

```
x=0 => arr[n-x][x] = arr[2-0][0] = arr[2][0];
  -> Empezamos mal, arr[2] se sale de los límites del array
x=1 => arr[n-x][x] = arr[2-1][1] = arr[1][1];
  -> Al menos está dentro de los límites del array
x=2 => arr[n-x][x] = arr[2-2][2] = arr[0][2];
  -> Seguimos fuera de los límites del array con el índice 2
x=3 => arr[n-x][x] = arr[2-3][3] = arr[-1][3];
  -> Remate final con acceso al índice -1.
```

Fíjate que en el ejercicio que te proponen, la segunda matriz es idéntica a la primera aplicando las siguientes transformaciones:

- El índice de las filas es igual al índice de las columnas invertido
- El índice de las columnas es igual al índice de las filas

Luego para imprimir la matriz girada:

```
for( int j=0;j<n; j++)
{
  for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n'; // No hay que olvidar el salto de línea al finalizar la fila
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: *El estándar de C++ indica que crear arreglos en la pila basados en tamaños dinámicos (su tamaño se basa en una variable) producen un resultado indeterminado*, creo que el estándar de C++ no habla de VLA; los VLA son aceptados como extensión de compilador y como tal funcionan de la manera esperada. Se desaconseja su uso precisamente por no ser portables.

Comment: `[C++11: 8.3.4/1]: In a declaration T D where D has the form 'D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt'` A mi `constant-expressionopt` me suena a un valor constante.

Comment: Tal vez sea la falta de café, pero no veo la relación de tu cita del estándar con lo mencionado sobre VLA. Estoy consultando [este documento](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) como estándar.

Comment: Los estándares como tal están disponibles únicamente pagando cuota. Se pueden encontrar en http://www.iso.org. Una referencia a lo que he dicho la puedes encontrar aquí: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays

Comment: Se puede usar el último borrador de C++ (que es gratis) el cuál es, salvo correcciones menores, idéntico al de pago. Disponible en la "*página oficial*" de C++: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Answer (score 0):

Muestro un ejemplo partiendo del código de la pregunta, pero es posible mejorarlo usando **c**, que es más rápido que **c++**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;                                     // Pide el tamaño de la matriz.

    int arr[n][n],
        r[n][n];                                  // Resultado.

    for(int f = 0; f < n; f++)                    // Pide el contenido de la matriz.
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
            cin >> arr[f][c];

    for(int f = 0; f < n; f++)                    // Rota la matriz original arr[][] sobre
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)                // la matriz resultado r[][]
            r[f][c] = arr[n - c - 1][f];

    for(int f = 0; f < n; f++)                    // Muestra el resultado.
    {
        cout << endl;
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
            cout << r[f][c] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora quedan dos tareas:

- Ajustar el código según el desafío de **omegaUp**.
- Traducirlo a **c** para lograr mayor eficiencia.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46626/discussion-on-answer-by-aprendiendo-net-c-problema-al-imprimir-matrices).