# ¿Cómo podría rotar la matriz?

Tags: c++, matrices

Me gustaría que me apoyaran a girar mi matriz para ambos lados derecha e izquierda. Veo que me funciona para una matriz cuadrada pero no para una de N*M que es lo que en realidad busco:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int fila,columna,m;

void  ingresarMatriz (int m[50][50], int &fila, int &columna);
void mostrarMatriz(int m[50][50], int fila, int columna);
void derecha(int m[50][50], int fila, int columna);
int mTem[50][50];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fila, columna, m[50][50];

ingresarMatriz(m, fila, columna);
mostrarMatriz(m, fila, columna);
int opc;

    cout << "\n";
    while(true){
         cout<<"1)Girar Izquierda\n 2)Girar Derecha\n 3) Salir\n";
         cout<<"Seleccione la Opcion: ";cin>>opc;
        //cin>>opc;

        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                derecha( m, fila,columna);
                break;
            case 2:
                //gira_derecha();
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
            default:
                cerr<<"Error";
                cin.get();
                system("cls");
                break;
        }
}
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void  ingresarMatriz (int m[50][50], int &fila, int &columna){
        m[0][0]=m[fila][columna];

    cout<<"Ingresar numero de filas de la matriz:";
    cin>>fila;
    cout<<"Ingresar numero de columnas de la matriz:";
    cin>>columna;

    for (int i = 0;i <fila;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j <columna;j++){            
            cout << "M(" << i+1 << "," << j+1 << ")= "; 
            cin >> m[i][j]; 
                    }       
    }

   cin.get();
}


void mostrarMatriz(int m[50][50], int fila, int columna)
{
     cout << "\n";
   cout << "La Matriz es Orden: " << fila << " X "<<columna << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++) {
         cout << "\t" <<m[i][j]<<"  ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
   }
}



void  derecha(int m[50][50], int fila, int columna){
      cout<<"Ha girado la matriz a la derecha"<<endl;
    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < fila; i++){
        t = 0;
        for(int j = fila-1; j >= 0;j--){
            mTem[i][t] = m[j][i];
            t++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < fila; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columna; j++){
            m[i][j] = mTem[i][j];
            cout<<m[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y marca el código correctamente.

Comment: Vaya, vaya, qué extraño que en esta pregunta no estén los editores estrella >:|

Comment: Sería bueno que definas que es rotar una matriz no cuadrada :D

Comment: @Máxima Alekz no me deja sugerir edición, por eso he dicho eso.

Comment: Puede que el contenido de [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26307/c-problema-al-imprimir-matrices) te ayude.

Comment: @MaximaAlekz no se si estaré en la lista de editores estrella... Lo que si sé es que en España es puente y algunos estamos de vacaciones ;)

Comment: Eyllanesc rotar una matriz significa que guire las posiciones osea los indices. Tanto a la derecha o como izquierda en 90grados asi sucesivamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int t;
for(int i = 0; i < fila; i++){
  t = 0;
  for(int j = fila-1; j >= 0;j--){
    mTem[i][t] = m[j][i]; t++;
  }
}
```

Girar la matriz implica que las filas se convierten en columnas y viceversa... La copia en `temp` no es correcta porque no estás teniendo en cuenta las columnas... Y si el número de filas no es igual al de columnas el algoritmo falla.

```
for(int i = 0; i < fila; i++){
  for(int j = columna; j++){
    mTem[j][i] = m[i][j]; t++;
  }
}
```

Aún así la rotación podría hacerse en un paso, pero estoy desde el móvil y ese código me gustaría poder probar el código antes de ponerlo.